# Capture the full call stack from within a Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have some code in a low-level library that needs to know if a certain class is above it in the call chain (we are migrating from one data store to another and I need to alert if someone is accessing the old store directly without going through a migration object).  Normally I would just check the stack trace, but there are times when the methods in this library are called from within a `Parallel.ForEach`, and that's disrupting the stack trace as most threads are running within the context of the thread pool.

Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CallstackSpike
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            new MigrationUtil().DoWork(10);
        }
    }

    internal class MigrationUtil
    {
        public void DoWork(int workCount)
        {
            new Fetcher().FetchStuff(workCount);
        }
    }

    internal class Fetcher
    {
        private readonly Worker worker = new Worker();

        public void FetchStuff(int workCount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Trying parallel foreach... ");
            ConcurrentBag<bool> results = new ConcurrentBag<bool>();
            Parallel.ForEach(
                Enumerable.Range(0, workCount),
                new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
                idx =>
                {
                    results.Add(worker.DoWork(idx));
                });

            bool result = results.Aggregate(true, (current, res) => current & res);
            Console.WriteLine("result: " + result);
        }
    }

    internal class Worker
    {
        private readonly Random random = new Random();

        public bool DoWork(int idx)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(random.Next(100, 500));

            string stackTrace = Environment.StackTrace;
            Console.WriteLine("IDX = {0}\n{1}\n", idx, stackTrace);

            return stackTrace.Contains("MigrationUtil");
        }
    }
}
```

With a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` of `4`, 75% of threads come from the thread pool, and their stack trace looks like this:

> ```
> at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
> at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
> at CallstackSpike.Worker.DoWork(Int32 idx) in C:\Dev\Spikes\CallstackSpike\CallstackSpike\Program.cs:line 56
> at CallstackSpike.Fetcher.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<FetchStuff>b__0(Int32 idx) in C:\Dev\Spikes\CallstackSpike\CallstackSpike\Program.cs:line 41
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass42_0`2.<PartitionerForEachWorker>b__1()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(Object obj)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
> at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
> at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
> ```

The remaining 25% of the time I can see the complete call stack:

> ```
> at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
> at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
> at CallstackSpike.Worker.DoWork(Int32 idx) in C:\Dev\Spikes\CallstackSpike\CallstackSpike\Program.cs:line 56
> at CallstackSpike.Fetcher.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<FetchStuff>b__0(Int32 idx) in C:\Dev\Spikes\CallstackSpike\CallstackSpike\Program.cs:line 41
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass42_0`2.<PartitionerForEachWorker>b__1()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteSelfReplicating(Task root)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(Object obj)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, Boolean taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.TryRunInline(Task task, Boolean taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InternalRunSynchronously(TaskScheduler scheduler, Boolean waitForCompletion)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunSynchronously(TaskScheduler scheduler)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.PartitionerForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](Partitioner`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 simpleBody, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body)
> at CallstackSpike.Fetcher.FetchStuff(Int32 workCount) in C:\Dev\Spikes\CallstackSpike\CallstackSpike\Program.cs:line 39
> at CallstackSpike.MigrationUtil.DoWork(Int32 workCount) in C:\Dev\Spikes\CallstackSpike\CallstackSpike\Program.cs:line 27
> at CallstackSpike.Program.Main() in C:\Dev\Spikes\CallstackSpike\CallstackSpike\Program.cs:line 13
> ```

So my question is, is there any way to query the current thread to know if it is due to a `Parallel.ForEach`, and if it is, where it came from before that?  Somewhere someone must know, I just don't know if the current thread has access to that information.

Comment: maybe put a lock on a variable in that higher level call, and then from the lower one see if the lock is there, if so then you know the higher one is in use?

Comment: Just a note: you see full stack in one case because Parallel.ForEach reuses current thread to execute one operation (because this thread anyway would be blocked waiting for foreach to complete, so why not use it for useful work).

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible by the way, because there is no notion of "parent" thread, so you cannot figure out which thread "created" current one (unless you manage this information yourself when creating thread). But with parallel.foreach one thread always runs on thread that called it, isn't that enough? You can throw exception on that thread only.

Comment: The function to get the StackTrace from another thread -that you might have provided as a Dowork() parameter - is unfortunately obsolete. The only solution would be to postprocess the results. For example, if last line contains contains "PerformWaitCallback()", add the current StackTrace.

Comment: You can pass the stack trace to Parallel.ForEach and then append it to current stack trace from the frame you want. It'll be little tricky but can be done.